# Maintaining SCCs in directed graphs (on-line, under edge deletion) with ES-trees

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, connected-components

I'm interested in efficiently maintaining the set of strongly connected components (SCC) in a *directed* (unweighted) graph under edge deletions only. While searching for ways I came across an article [1] that uses a generalised version of EvenShiloach-trees (ES-trees) [2] to maintain shortest path trees for the graph.

I have looked into ES-trees and understand how they work in the setting of **un**directed graphs, however a modification should allows to maintain a shortest path tree in *directed* graphs [3] but I can't work out how to do it.

Does anyone know of an example how ES-trees can be modified to maintain a shortest path tree under edge deletion?

---

[1] [Bernstein, A., Probst, M., & Wulff-Nilsen, C. (2019). Decremental strongly-connected components and single-source reachability in near-linear time.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03615)

[2] [Even, S., & Shiloach, Y. (1979). An on-line edge-deletion problem (No. CS Technion report CS0154). Computer Science Department, Technion.](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/1979/CS/CS0154.pdf)

[3] [Henzinger, M. R., & King, V. (1995, October). Fully dynamic biconnectivity and transitive closure. In Proceedings of IEEE 36th Annual Foundations of Computer Science (pp. 664-672). IEEE.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/492668)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03615